# Does Challenge between moses and qaroon qualify as mubahala

Tags: salat, prophet-musa

I am referring to text from "stories of the prophets" (ibn kathir, English version, darussalam print).

Qaroon said Allah preffered you(moses) for prophethood over me. And Allah preffered me over you in wealth. Let me invoke divine curse upon you. And then you invoke upon me.

Both reach a place, moses asked will you invoke Allah first or me. Qaroon said he will go first. Nothing happens. Then moses invokes curse. Earth swallows qaroon.

> And We caused the earth to swallow him and his home. And there was for him no company to aid him other than Allah, nor was he of those who [could] defend themselves. ( Quran 28:81 )

My Question is does this mutual challenge qualify as mubahala?

Comment: In the literal meaning mubahala simply means mutual cursing on whoever is wrong, so this story matches that. Are you looking based on some qualifications for what counts as a mubahala other than the literal meaning?

Comment: Since the english translation doesnt mention sources , I was looking to answers from arabic readers. I didnt comprehend disagreement between qaroon and musa.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to know whether Ibn Kathir called it a mubahala? Or do you want more explanation on the story and what the disagreement was? I am afraid I still don't quite get what you are looking for.

Comment: I want more explanation on disagreement and the source.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you edit the question to more accurately reflect that. Ask "what was the disagreement between Musa and Qaroon and what are the sources" or something similar to that.